# How to query compare between rows in collection ElasticSearch

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch

I have data in Elasaticsearch like this:

```
 {"number1":1 ,"result":0 , "date":"2018-01-17T01:00:57Z"}
{"number1":5 ,"result":0 , "date":"2018-01-17T02:00:57Z"}
{"number1":6 ,"result":0 , "date":"2018-01-17T03:00:57Z"}
{"number1":4 ,"result":0 , "date":"2018-01-17T04:00:57Z"}
```

I want to query result:

```
{"number1":1 ,"result":4 , "date":"2018-01-17T01:00:57Z"}
{"number1":5 ,"result":1 , "date":"2018-01-17T02:00:57Z"}
{"number1":6 ,"result":-2 , "date":"2018-01-17T03:00:57Z"}
{"number1":4 ,"result":0 , "date":"2018-01-17T04:00:57Z"}
```

Note: result=(number1 in second row)-(number1 in first row)...

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.